# How to use UTF-8 in ng-view?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, character-encoding, ng-view

That's a silly question, but I can't manage to make my `<ng-view>` inherit `<meta charset="UTF-8">` from the main containing page.

I have something like this in index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BalrogApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- Some css and data... -->
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 50px">

  <div header></div>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
  <div footer></div>

<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- Some JS includes... -->

</body>
</html>
```

The view is set in routeConfiguration.js :

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/requestsList.html',
      controller: 'requestsController',
      controllerAs: 'r'
    })
    .when('/projects', {
      templateUrl: 'views/projectsList.html',
      controller: 'projectsController',
      controllerAs: 'p',
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$route', function($rootScope, $route) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    document.title = $route.current.title;
  });
}]);
```

But the content in requestList.html or any view isn't UTF-8 encoded.

How can I make all my views use UTF-8 encoding ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I did the following to fix it.

index.html
-With notepad I checked the encode type, it was correct UTF-8.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

home.html, it is managed by the routeProvider, and shown within ng-view

```
<div class="well">
 <div ng-view></div> 
</div>
```

When I checked the encode type for the home.html it was ANSI, I have just saved all the htmls as UTF-8. Problem solved

[Encoded in ANSI - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AbFm.jpg)